# Jetpack compose can not inspect in AS Layout Inspector

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack compose can not inspect in AS Layout Inspector.
Is there any tools can inspect compose layoutnode.

Comment: do you have Android Studio or IntelliJ? For me I get an error when trying in IntelliJ but it works fine in the latest version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the Jetpack Compose [Beta launch,](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/02/announcing-jetpack-compose-beta.html) the latest version of Android Studio has a version of the Layout Inspector that supports inspecting jetpack compose layouts:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#layout-inspector
[image]

Comment: Looks like it works in Android Studio but not in IntelliJ right now

Comment: doesn't work on latest AS release (chipmunk). tried on several compose demo projects

Comment: still doesn't work in the latest dolphin

Answer (score 37):

After Enabling **Enable View Attributes** in **Device's Developer Options**  solved the issue for me in Android 12 Device

Comment: For me it was Enable viewing attributes.

Comment: Same solution but Android 10

Answer (score 7):

For me, I have to do this to make LayoutInspector works with Compose (Enabling Enable View Attributes in Device's Developer Options doesn't work).

```
// Before
packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
}

// After
packagingOptions {
    // resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
}
```

It's mentioned in [the Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/244120504#comment16). The quote from the user comment:

> On my project, i had a similar issue where the layout inspector was not working (the compose views where not shown). I solved it removing this line in my build.gradle :

```
packagingOptions {
    resources.excludes += setOf(
        "META-INF/*.version", <= Removing this line
        "META-INF/proguard/*",
        "META-INF/*.kotlin_module",
        "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES",
        "META-INF/AL2.0",
        "META-INF/LGPL2.1",
        "META-INF/*.properties",
        "/*.properties"
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio's Layout Inspector does not currently support Compose. Until then you can use [Square's Radiography](https://github.com/square/radiography) for debugging, which will print your view hierarchy.

Check out the documentation to use it with Compose: https://github.com/square/radiography#jetpack-compose-support

Answer (score 1):

I tried different devices, emulator versions, android studio updates. But I found only one successfully case when I'm able to see components tree with recomposition counts:

1. Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 1
2. Emulator API 34
3. SDK Tools - installed Layout Inspector image server API 31-34

Answer (score -1):

Question is not very clear. If I understand it correctly, may be you are not seeing your app in the `Select a process` option of the `Layout inspector`.

https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector#inspect-compose-semantics

> Make sure your app is using an API level of 29 or higher, and Compose
> 1.2.0-alpha03 or higher. Then, deploy your app as you normally would.